# Laravel - Prefijar y nombrar una ruta de forma personalizada

Tags: php, laravel

He configurado el prefijo y nombre de rutas personalizado para un determinado controlador de recursos de API según como se explica en la documentación de Laravel ("[Route Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes)" y "[Route Name Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-name-prefixes)").

Así que he creado el controlador de recursos de API relacionado con el modelo User de esta forma:

php artisan make:controller AP/admin/UserController --api

Y, a continuación, queriendo que todas las rutas asociadas estén precedidas con el término de "admin" al igual que los nombres de ruta relacionados, he configurado este bloque de código dentro del archivo "./routes/api.php":

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::name('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::apiResources([
            'users' => 'API\admin\UserController',
        ]);
    });
});
```

Tras guardar los cambios en el archivo comentado, si ejecuto el siguiente comando en la terminal de `php artisan route:list`, me sale un correcto listado de rutas dónde se plasma las rutas con el prefijo y nombre de rutas configurados del estilo:

`GET|HEAD  |  api/admin/users  |  admin.users.index  | 
 App\Http\Controllers\API\admin\UserController@index  |  api`

Entonces, he querido dar una nueva vuelta de tuerca al bloque de código para que, en vez de pasarle una cadena, pasarle una variable de esta forma:

```
$patron = 'admin';
$patron_nombre = $patron . '.';
Route::prefix($patron)->group(function () {
    Route::name($patron_nombre)->group(function () {
        Route::apiResources([
            'users' => 'API\admin\UserController',
        ]);
    });
});
```

Pero, al ejecutar el comando de listado de rutas (`php artisan route:list`), de primeras, me indica el error de "Undefined variable: patron_nombre" en la línea correspondiente a `Route::name...`.
En ese momento, me ha dado por pensar que, igual, por problemas de ámbito o algo parecido, no le llega la variable. Por ello, he probado por pasárselo de esta forma, como parámetro de la función anónima:

```
$patron = 'admin';
$patron_nombre = $patron . '.';
Route::prefix($patron)->group(function ($patron_nombre) {
    Route::name($patron_nombre)->group(function () {
        Route::apiResources([
            'users' => 'API\admin\UserController',
        ]);
    });
});
```

En este momento, al ejecutar el comando de listado de rutas, me devuelve este mensaje de ERROR referido al archivo "/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteGroup.php" en su línea 90:

"Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Router could not be converted to string"

Así que, ¿es posible conseguir lo que pretendo o no es posible?, ¿cuál sería la forma correcta de pasar la variable para que pudiera ser asignada como prefijo del nombre de ruta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas utilizar la variable `$patron_nombre`, debes heredarla del contexto superior con `use (...)`. De la forma como lo estás haciendo ahora lo estás pasando como parámetro de entrada del callback y Laravel (PHP) lo toma de forma distinta a lo que pretendes hacer, de ahí el error que te muestra.

Lo que estás buscando es:

```
Route::prefix($patron)->group(function () use ($patron_nombre) {
    ...
```

Comment: Muy bien, totalmente correcto. Muchas gracias.